# How to appendChild a component in DOM with VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I followed this tutorial https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/

My component :

```
const button = Vue.component('button', {

props: {
    id: String,
    color: String
},

data: function() {

    return {

        count: 0
    }

},

template: 

`
  <div class="button">
     {{ count }}
  </div>
`
});
```

The html :

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>


<body>

<div id="app">

 <main id="main" ref="container">

   <span @click="add">Add</span>
    
 </main>

</div>

</body>


<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>


</html>
```

All is fine but at this step I get the error "instance is not a html node" How to make vue component as a html node ?

```
    ComponentClass = Vue.extend(button)
    instance = new ComponentClass()
    this.$refs.container.appendChild(instance.$el)
```

Comment: Add the child in view way. Name the component so that it does not clash with existing heml component `const button = Vue.component('v-button', {` and the use in html like `<v-button></v-button>`